# Sub Menu Alignment Which Property Missing

Tags: html, wordpress, css

Please see this screencast. I have some alignment issue in Sub Menu. http://screencast.com/t/aFnXTQOdUn2g

what I want is that drop down should open not from the parent menu bottom, but just adjacent to parent menu. like this - http://screencast.com/t/iwhthlc9MD

I tried all the properties couldn't do this. What am I missing. Please help.

Comment: can you provide your code here it will be better

Comment: Add your html and css here

Comment: http://trafficopedia.com/charito5/1/ This might help. Go to sermon and then the last drop down in it. you can see causes is UP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:relative`

Second level li

```
ul li ul li{position:relative}
```

Comment: Thanks sir Can you tell me exactly where should I put It.

Comment: You are wonderful sir. It works can You guide me where can I study all these things in details.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu open"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 4</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.4</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

Comment: and add relative class to the appropriate element.

Comment: Currently it is not in  bootstrap, Right?

Comment: can u guide me what should I place in mu custom.css file sir?

Comment: `.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}`

Comment: use the same class like above html, it will help you

Comment: Didn't worked However this solution of the above poster worked:
ul li ul li{position:relative}